# How to enable installation of apk over usb debugging if denied permission earlier?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, miui

I want to use Redmi Note 7 Pro for debugging my react native applications over ADB. But I accidentally denied installing apps over USB and chose don't ask again. Now I'm not able to allow it.

I've tried:

1. Disabling & enabling Install via USB in Developer Options.
2. Turn off developer options & enable it again.

But it has not worked out so far. And I'm not able to find anything related to this in google searches. I'm also not getting any popup asking when I try to install over USB.

I get this error:

> `java.lang.SecurityException`: You need the `android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open the `terminal` of your computer.
2. Navigate to the Android `SDK` folder.
3. run `cd platform-tools`
4. run `sudo ./adb kill-server`
5. run `sudo ./adb devices`

All this with your phone connected via USB, the message should pop up again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried revoking permission and connecting mobile again ?

"Revoke USB debugging authorisations"
[image]

Comment: I found the solution, I had to disable MIUI Optimization, everything worked properly after that.